# ValueError when saving plot.ly image in Python

Tags: python, plotly

In Google Colab I'd like to save a static image to Gdrive. I'm following [the instructions](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) and installing kaleido before using write_image(), but am still getting ValueError. Any idea how to fix this?

ValueError:
Image export using the "kaleido" engine requires the kaleido package, which can be installed using pip:

$ pip install -U kaleido

```
!pip install -U kaleido
import kaleido
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/', force_remount=False)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    y=df_raw['Close'],
    mode='lines+markers',
    name='Original Plot'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=pd.Series(df_raw[col].to_list())[pd.Series(df_raw[col].to_list())!=0].index,
    y=[df_raw['Close'][j] for j in df_raw[df_raw[col]!=0].index],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=8,
        color='red',
        symbol='cross'
    ),
    name='Pattern'
))

fig.write_image("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Test.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding to my own question for the community's benefit. See [this comment](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/131#issuecomment-1082652642) - when using write_image(), the target output file and the folder path may not contain spaces.